# Azure DevOps pipelines passing environment variables into PS Script on an Ubuntu Host

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a Stage that runs my Terraform Code, but I need to whitelist the agent IP on my Azure SQL server, so I have a PowerShell script that can handle this, however, the environment variables inside the script (for instance $env:company_name) are all showing as null I believe because its bash. Not sure....the part of YAML is shown below. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks

******************** YAML from pipeline**************************

```
    steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Install AZ Modules'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
       sudo /usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/STAGE2/Scripts/buildazmodule.ps1"
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Add Firewall Rules'
    inputs:
      targetType: filePath
      filePath: './STAGE2/Scripts/firewallrules.ps1'
  - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
    inputs:
      terraformVersion: '0.12.28'
  - script: terraform version
    displayName: 'Terraform Version'
  - script: az cloud set --name $(cloud)
    displayName: 'Set Cloud'
  - script:  az login --service-principal -u $(client_id) -p $(client_secret) --tenant $(tenant_id)
    displayName: 'Log Into Azure'
  - script: terraform init -backend-config=resource_group_name=$(sg_resource_group) -backend-config="storage_account_name=$(sg_name)" -backend-config="container_name=$(blob_storage)" -backend-config="access_key=$(sg_accesskey)" -backend-config="key=$(state_file)" -backend-config="environment=$(cloud_environment_name)"
    displayName: 'Terraform Init'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/STAGE2
  - script: terraform plan -var="client_id=$(client_id)" -var="client_secret=$(client_secret)" -var="tenant_id=$(tenant_id)" -var="subscription_id=$(subscription_id)" -var="environment=$(cloud_environment_name)" -var="company_name=$(company_name)" -var="cloudsitename=$(cloudsitename)" -var="envtype=$(envtype)"  -var="builddate=$(builddate)"  -var="is_public=$(is_public)" -var="region=$(region)"  -var="os_image_skey=$(os_image_skey)"  -var="is_osmanaged_ad=$(is_osmanaged_ad)" -var="remote_tenant=$(remote_tenant)" -var="is_fedramp=$(is_fedramp)" -var="level=$(level)" -var="onestream_version=$(onestream_version)" -out="out.plan"
    displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/STAGE2
  - script: terraform apply out.plan
    displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/STAGE2
```

************************ Part of script code***********************

```
$envtype = $env:envtype
$CompanyName = $env:company_name
$CompanyNameTemp = $CompanyName.ToLower() #input production environment name e.g. the "tmfgroup" in rg"tmfgroup" ***PIPELINE VAR***
$CompanyName = ($CompanyNametemp.subString(0, [System.Math]::Min(8, $CompanyNametemp.Length))).Trim()
$sgname = "sg${CompanyName}"
$rgname = "rg${CompanyName}"
$kvName = "kv${CompanyName}"
$sqlName = "sql${CompanyName}${envtype}"
```

*************************** Error**********************

InvalidOperation: /home/vsts/work/1/s/STAGE2/Scripts/firewallrules.ps1:4
Line |
4 |  $CompanyNameTemp = $CompanyName.ToLower() #input production environme …
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: Can you try `$env:COMPANY_NAME`?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with  Krzysztof Madej.

As far as I know, linux system is **case sensitive.**

When you set the variable in azure devops, it will be converted to uppercase letters in environment variables.

For example:

[image]

So when you use the environment variable in Linux system, you need to change the format as
`$env:COMPANY_NAME`.

By the way, you could use the script to output all environment variables(e.g. `env | sort`).

Then you could check the environment variable format.